# Building a retaining wall

Tags: retaining-wall

I live in Zone 5. Frost level is 36".  I need to install a retaining wall against a bank that is about 30'.  I am wondering how deep or wide of footing I should install. Retaining wall will need to be 6-8 ft tall.

Comment: Sounds like you will need serious ground anchors as well.

Comment: I would definately contact a civil engineer/designer. Quick computing with accordance to local codes should do.

Comment: It's going to depend on what kind of soil you have, you'll likely need to have anchors or geomeshes to support the wall. Additionally if the soil above is expected to hold a lot of weight (eg pavement or structures) the construction is even more demanding. Your jurisdiction likely requires a building plan in advance and multiple inspections. We need more details to be of any help.